# How to clear/delete/remove my RecyclerView in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

When I search for a user in my database, it populates the RecyclerView, but when I make another search, and it can't find the user, I want it to also remove the RecyclerView content, but the old users content stays in the RecyclerView until I search for an existing user, then it changes to the new users content.

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_search_user)
    public void onSearchBtnClicked(View view) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Search button clicked");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(etSearchUser.getText())) {
            userNameSearch = etSearchUser.getText().toString();

            if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No internet, searching offline", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mOwner = Owner.getByUsername(userNameSearch);
                if(mOwner != null) {
                    searchUserByUserName(userNameSearch);
                } else {
                    // I want the RecyclerView to be empty at this point.
                    tvGitHubUser.setText("was not found offline");
                }
            } else {
                loadRepository(userNameSearch);
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Owner is empty, searching online");
            }
        }
    }
```

initRecycleView()

```
mGithubRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.github_repository_recyclerview);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mGithubLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mGithubRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGithubLayoutManager);
        mGithubRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply, call `recyclerView.setAdapter(null);`

If you can show me your adapter code, I can provide better method.

Comment: I also tried to create a clearItem() in the adapter, and then calling `repositories.remove(x);
                notifyItemRemoved(x);` in a for loop with item.size(), but this also works. Thanks!

Comment: You could also do `repositories.clear(); notifyDataSetChanged();`